# Алгоритм вычленения >3 <6 значного числа

Tags: java

Требуется алгоритм который бы вытащил >3 <6 значное число из строки.

**К примеру, есть строка**: `22 Код - 3653`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://ideone.com/vqDYvL

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Ideone {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d{4,5}\\b");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("22 Код - 3653 восьмизначное 45678666 и ещё код 45678");

    while (matcher.find()) {
      int x = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
      System.out.println(x);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Для `45678666` же тоже сработает, хотя оно и 8-значное.

Comment: @Suvitruf, исправил.

Comment: спасибо, работает